# How Add delivery date Column in Sales_oroder_create_index

Tags: magento2

I am a beginner at Magento. I want to add delivery data UI component in admin->sales_order_create_index page. How Can I Do it? Any Help Please. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can download this extension and consult their code. This utility is completely free: https://www.magetop.com/magento-2-delivery-date-extension.html